# TypeScript fails to select correct function signature

Tags: typescript, overloading, signature

I have a function written in TypeScript that performs binary search. Usually, I'll let it run on number arrays, but I wanted to make it more generic. This is the code I got now:

```js
export function binarySearchLessOrEqual(arr: number[], key: number): number;
export function binarySearchLessOrEqual<T>(arr: T[], key: number, valueGetter?: (x: T) => number): number {
    ...
}
```

For the generic version, it takes a third argument `valueGetter` that maps each value from `arr` to some numerical value, which is then used for the binary search.

An example of me calling it:

```js
interface Thing {
    x: number
}

let numberArr: [0, 1, 2];
binarySearchLessOrEqual(numberArr, 1);

let thingArr: Thing[] = [{x: 0}, {x: 1}, {x: 2}];
binarySearchLessOrEqual(thingArr, 1, (o) => o.x);
```

`binarySearchLessOrEqual` using the `numberArr` works as expected, however calling it with `thingArr` throws **Expected 2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)**.

Why? Clearly, since `thingArr` is not type `number[]`, TypeScript should try to call the function with the second signature, which has three arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I got it. Turns out I needed to specify another overload for the additional signature that I wanted. Now I got:

```js
export function binarySearchLessOrEqual(arr: number[], key: number): number;
export function binarySearchLessOrEqual<T>(arr: T[], key: number, valueGetter: (x: T) => number): number;
export function binarySearchLessOrEqual<T>(arr: T[], key: number, valueGetter?: (x: T) => number): number {
    ...
}
```